# How to addJs using layout?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, javascript, phtml

My current **config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
<modules>
    <inchoo_orders>
        <version>0.0.3</version>
    </inchoo_orders>
</modules>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <orders>
                <file>inchoo/orders/orders.xml</file>
            </orders>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>

<global>
    <models>
        <inchoo_orders>
            <class>Inchoo_Orders_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>inchoo_orders_resource</resourceModel>
        </inchoo_orders>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <inchoo_orders_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Inchoo_Orders</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </inchoo_orders_setup>
    </resources>

    <blocks>
        <inchoo_orders>
            <class>Inchoo_Orders_Block</class>
        </inchoo_orders>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <inchoo_orders>
            <class>Inchoo_Orders_Helper</class>
        </inchoo_orders>
    </helpers>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <inchoo_orders before="Mage_Adminhtml">Inchoo_Orders_Adminhtml</inchoo_orders>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

 </config>
```

My current layout file orders.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <layout>
<default>
<!--<adminhtml_orders_index>-->
    <reference name="js">
        <block type="core/template" template="inchoo/orders/inline-edit.phtml"/>
    </reference>
<!--</adminhtml_orders_index >-->
</default>
</layout>
```

layout file location:
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/inchoo/orders/orders.xml
template file location: /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/inchoo/orders/inline-edit.phtml

What I would like to achieve is according to the tutorial instead of inserting js into  keep it in phtml.
(I can add into  but then there is a problem with url in ajax as tutorial author mentioned).

Help! Please!
I tried almos all possible combination to make it work :(

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: remove space between `core / template ` and  make it as ` core/template` and see other changes in your question

Comment: no no no, these spaces I added just to make sure it will be displayed in post properly, it's not an issue

Comment: ok I corrected it. So it is exactly as in post, what I must change to make it work ?

Comment: RiccardoT: what i'm trying to do is load phtml in which i have some javascript required for my module. I can add .js file with no problem but because as I already explained there is a problem with php embedded to get url so as the tutorial author suggested script should be in phtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your config.xml file add below code your adminhtml node

```
 <adminhtml>
    <args>
                <modules>
                    <inchoo_orders before="Mage_Adminhtml">Inchoo_Orders_Adminhtml</inchoo_orders>
                </modules>
     </args>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <bar>
                <file>my_layout.xml</file>
            </bar>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

and your my_layout.xml file write below code

```
<layout>
<adminhtml_sales_index>
    <reference name="head">
        < block type="core/template" template="inchoo/orders/inline_edit.phtml" / >
    </reference>
 </adminhtml_sales_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: still nothing :(ALredy tested all possible options and no positive result ;(

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: Finally I managed to add js to the head byt not as tutorial author suggested :) added it as a js file ;( and it can cause other problems but ... will see ;)

Comment: What problem it cause tell me if I can help you

Comment: I couldn't make it work as in tutorial where javascript was placed in phtml instead of in separate js file. I managed to make it work as .js but now i have a problem with url generated. so I must  find the way to make it work as planned

Comment: can you show how you are trying to make some code or something

Comment: Sure, check updated above.

Comment: have you created file in `app/design/adminhtml/template/inchoo/orders/inline_edit.phtml` in this path

Comment: Yes ;(
Check updated post